# What happens in C, when a larger datatype (e.g. int) is converted to a smaller datatype (e.g. short)?

Tags: c, type-conversion

I am playing with type conversions when I came across this in the following code.

```
int i = 123456;
short s = i;
printf("%i",s);
```

Here an int value is converted to short implicitly by C compiler. Printing this value, results in -7616 on the console output. I understand that short has a smaller range than that of int but I need to know how C language came to this value -7616 from 123456 instead of truncating it, which I guess is the intuitive option.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28389750/narrowing-conversion-of-65280-from-int-to-short-int-inside. It's implementation defined

Answer (score 8):

The value is being truncated, but not in the way you expect.

The decimal value 123456 has hex value `0x1E240`.  When assigning this value to a `short`, which in your case appears to be 16 bits, it takes just the lower 16 bits, which is `0xE240`.

If `s` were an `unsigned short`, it would have the value 57920.  But because it's signed, the value is interpreted as such.  Since your machine appears to be using [two's complement representation](http://www.vb-helper.com/tutorial_twos_complement.html#TwosComplement) for negative numbers, the decimal equivalent of `0xE240` is -7616 (= 57920 - 65536).

Note that this behavior is implementation defined, so you can't depend on this happening on different machines or different compilers.

Answer (score 1):

Values get truncated during this conversion in such a way that the less significant bits are preserved, but the higher bits are lost.  This is consistent whether you use a big or little endian machine.

In your specific example, 123456 is written as 11110001001000000 in binary.
**Keep in mind that ints use 4 bytes, so there are a bunch of leading zeros that I omitted from that number**.  Shorts are limited to 2 bytes, immediately truncating the number to 1110001001000000 strictly.  Notice that there is a 1 in front, which in 2's complement would immediately indicate a negative number. 
Going through the 2's complement process shows how you would get the result you did.

**In C, when you convert an int to a short, you are already asking for trouble.**  In cases like when working with .wav files, you typically use int datatypes for manipulation of attributes before using a series of if statements to control truncation.

```
//you will need to #include <limits.h>

int i = 123456;
short s;

if(i > SHRT_MIN && i < SHRT_MAX) //if your int is within the range of shorts
{
    s = i;
}


//if your int is too large or too negative, you can control the truncation

if(i < SHRT_MIN) //if int is too negative
{
    i=SHRT_MIN;
}

else //if int is too positive
{
    i=SHRT_MAX;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine a 4bit integer is converted to a 2bit integer. The first bit determines whether the number is positive `(0)` or negative `(1)`. 
`0111 (dec: 7)` converts to `11 (dec: -1)`. It will cut higher bits. And since the first bit `1` represents `-` it will be negative.

Answer (score 0):

Data type `short` (2 byte size) has values from [-32768] to [32767].

```
int main()
{
    int i = 32767;
    short c = i;
    printf("%d\n",c);
    c = i+1;
    printf("%d\n",c);
    c = i+2;
    printf("%d\n",c);
}

//Output:
32767
-32768  << rolling
-32767  << rolling
```

If you see the values keep on rolling from least value (-32768) to max values if `short` is assigned values greater than allowed max value i.e [32767]

```
int main()
{
    int i = -32768;
    short c = i;
    printf("%d\n",c);
    c = i-1;
    printf("%d\n",c);
    c = i-2;
    printf("%d\n",c);
}

//Output:
-32768
32767  << rolling
32766  << rolling
```

If you see the values keep on rolling from max value (32767) to least values if `short` is assigned values less than allowed min value i.e [-32768]